# Not able to set dropdownlist at page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting first time this kind of problem

I am setting value of dropdownlist at page load from dataset 
    But this is auto setting 0 index .....
My code :

```
ddlEbitda.SelectedValue = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["acq_ebitda"].ToString();
```

I checked at immediate windows ...

```
objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["acq_ebitda"].ToString();
```

"Between 40-60 %"    ( come value from data set is right)

```
ddlEbitda.SelectedValue
"Up to 10 Million Dollar "           ( this is default value setting )
```

I tried many different code to solve  this problem :

```
    ddlEbitda.ClearSelection();
    string Ebitda = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["acq_ebitda"].ToString();
    ddlEbitda.Items.FindByValue(Ebitda).Selected = true;


    string Ebitda = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["acq_ebitda"].ToString();
    ddlEbitda.SelectedIndex = ddlEbitda.Items.IndexOf(ddlEbitda.Items.FindByValue(Ebitda));
```

But still not able to solve this problem ....truth is I am not able to understand what is problem .....

Comment: Is there a `ListItem` with a `.Value` of *Between 40-60 %*? Or is its `.Value` something else and its `.Text` *Between 40-60 %*? Its `.Value` must be `Between 40-60 %` or it must only have its `.Text` set (then its `.Value` will be the same as `.Text`). Also, the casing must the same as returned from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
string value=objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["acq_ebitda"].ToString();
ddlEbitda.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

But make sure when you are binding the dropdown with DataSource, at that time `acq_ebitda` should be `DataValueField`.

If it is `DataTextField` then you should try something like this

```
ddlEbitda.Items.FindByText(value).Selected = true;
```

Comment: thanks friend Problem was very small - space problem when i was selecting value that is inserted blank space with option  "Up to 10 Million Dollar " I remove this space ....can I can use Trim() also at the time of saving and retrieving data ..thanks again

Comment: yes you can use `trim` to remove the spaces from start and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the DropDownList is populated/bound inside this code block in the Page_Load method

```
    If (!IsPostBack)
    {
    }
```

and immediately after set the selected item.

```
    ddlEbitda.SelectedValue
```

Comment: Thanks ... I changed code but still not working                           if (qsAcq_id != 0)
            {
               if( !IsPostBack)
                   LoadData();
            }

Comment: Are you binding the `DropDownList` control to the `objDataSet`? Also is the 'ddlEbitda` created programmatically in the code-behind or declaratively in the ASPX page? Can you also confirm that the `Text` and `Value` properties of `ddlEbitda.ListItem` object contain the same text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whether your dropdown list is correctly bound to the dataset and data is populated . specially make sure the value you are assigning is in the item list. you can easily check with quick watch in VS so you can make sure the value you are assigning is inside the dropdown items. because the way you are doing is OK